# Plot of some complicated functions containing special functions under both Sum and Product

Tags: plotting, special-functions, summation, products

I am trying to plot the $|f(\theta,\phi)|^2$, where the expression of $f(\theta,\phi)$ is as under:
$$ f =\sum_{n_j}\Pi_{j_x,j_y,j_z}P_{n_j}\sum_{l}A_s \text{e}^{-ia(l_1q_x+l_2q_y+l_3q_z)}\times 
    \exp{(\frac{q_x^2l_{j_x}^2}{MN})}\times L_{\nu_{j_x}}(\frac{2 q_x^2l_{j_x}^2}{MN})\times
    \exp{(\frac{-q_y^2l_{j_y}^2}{MN})}\times L_{\nu_{j_y}}(\frac{2q_y^2l_{j_y}^2}{MN})\times
    \exp{\frac{(-q_z^2l_{j_z}^2}{MN})}\times L_{\nu_{j_z}}(\frac{2 q_z^2l_{j_z}^2}{MN})$$
The expression of $P_{n_j}$ is shown under function $f1$.
The input/code, I have written in mathematica for the said purpose is as under:

```
ClearAll
w1[w0_, j1_, N1_] := 2*w0*Abs[Sin[(\[Pi]*j1)/N1]]
w2[w0_, j2_, N2_] := 2*w0*Abs[Sin[(\[Pi]*j2)/N2]]
w3[w0_, j3_, N3_] := 2*w0*Abs[Sin[(\[Pi]*j3)/N3]]
q1[k_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := k*Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]
q2[k_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := k*Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]
q3[k_, \[Theta]_] := k*(Cos[\[Theta]] - 1)
L1[h_, M_, w0_, j1_, N1_] := (h/(M*w1[w0, j1, N1]))^(1/2)
L2[h_, M_, w0_, j2_, N2_] := (h/(M*w2[w0, j2, N2]))^(1/2)
L3[h_, M_, w0_, j3_, N3_] := (h/(M*w2[w0, j3, N3]))^(1/2)
f1[n1_, n2_, n3_, w0_, j1_, j2_, j3_, N1_, N2_, N3_, h_, kb_, T_] := 
 Exp[((n1 + 1/2) h*w1[w0, j1, N1] + (n2 + 1/2) h*
      w2[w0, j2, N2] + (n3 + 1/2) h*w3[w0, j3, N3])/(kb*T)]/
 Sum[Exp[((s1 + 1/2) h*w1[w0, j1, N1] + (s2 + 1/2) h*
       w2[w0, j2, N2] + (s3 + 1/2) h*w3[w0, j3, N3])/(kb*T)], {s1, 0, 
   10, 1}, {s2, 0, 10, 1}, {s3, 0, 10, 1}]
f2[n1_, n2_, n3_, w0_, j1_, j2_, j3_, N1_, N2_, N3_, h_, 
  k_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, M_, N_, a_] := 
 Sum[Exp[-I*
     a (l1*q1[k, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + l2*q2[k, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
       l3*q3[k, \[Theta]])], {l1, 0, 20, 1}, {l2, 0, 20, 1}, {l3, 0, 
    20, 1}] Exp[(-q1[k, \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*L1[h, M, w0, j1, N1]^2)/(
   M*N)]*LaguerreL[n1, (
   2*q1[k, \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*L1[h, M, w0, j1, N1]^2)/(M*N)]* 
  Exp[(-q2[k, \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*L2[h, M, w0, j2, N2]^2)/(M*N)]*
  LaguerreL[n2, (2*q2[k, \[Theta], \[Phi]]^2*L2[h, M, w0, j2, N2]^2)/(
   M*N)]* Exp[(-q3[k, \[Theta]]^2*L1[h, M, w0, j3, N3]^2)/(M*N)]*
  LaguerreL[n3, (2*q3[k, \[Theta]]^2*L3[h, M, w0, j3, N3]^2)/(M*N)]
F1[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
 Sum[Product[
   f1[n1, n2, n3, 1000, j1, j2, j3, 100, 100, 100, 1*10^-34, 
     1.3*10^-23, 298]*
    f2[n1, n2, n3, 1000, j1, j2, j3, 100, 100, 100, 1*10^-34, 
     2 \[Pi]/(1*10^-9), \[Theta], \[Phi], 200, 10^6, 3*10^-10], {j1, 
    1, 10, 1}, {j2, 1, 10, 1}, {j3, 1, 10, 1}], {n1, 0, 10, 1}, {n2, 
   0, 10, 1}, {n3, 0, 10, 1}]
Plot[Abs[F1[\[Theta], \[Pi]/3]]^2, {\[Theta], -\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/3}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

No output is shown in Mathematica even after a long time.No error message has been shown.  I have also tried to get the result by replacing Sum by NSum but no such change is observed.

Would you kindly help me to understand where the error lies or suggest me some other way to represent the same, such that I can get the desired plot.
Thanking you,

Comment: `F1` does 1000 iterations for `Product` and for each of those does 1000 iterations for `Sum` and for each of those `f2` which does 8000 iterations for `Sum` and for each of those `f1` does 1000 iterations for `Sum` So that is eight billion iterations AND that is just to produce a SINGLE POINT for `Plot` which likely does 1000 iterations for points. So you cannot understand why eight trllion iterations doesn't  instantly produce a plot? IF instead in `F1` I do only ONE iteration of `Sum` and ONE iteration of `Product` and I do 12 iterations for a `Table` instead of `Plot` then I see a result.

Comment: Try replacing `Plot[Abs[F1[\[Theta],\[Pi]/3]]^2,{\[Theta],-\[Pi]/3,\[Pi]/3},PlotRange->Full]` with `ListPlot[Table[{\[Theta],Abs[F1[\[Theta],\[Pi]/3]]^2},{\[Theta],-\[Pi]/3,\[Pi]/3,\[Pi]/9}]` and see whether 9 points shows you enough of the plot. If not then make`\[Pi]/9` smaller a little at a time until you can see enough or you cannot wait any longer for it to finish.

Comment: The definitions for `w1`, `w2`, and `w3` have identical patterns and are therefore redundant. `w2` and `w3` can be eliminated. Likewise, eliminate `q2`, `L2`, and `L3`. In the definition for `F1` use `Set` along with `Simplify` rather than `SetDelayed`. This will radically reduce the `LeafCount` of the definition. Look for additional streamlining to increase efficiency.

Comment: @Bill thanks for your comment...I shall try to follow that

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, Thanks for your reply. Yes..It will help me to understand the programming in  different situations like this..